# Rufus FreeDOS option for CF is not bootable

Tags: bios, freedos

When I try to prepare a bootable FreeDOS on my CF disk my old 386SX laptop (AMI Bios from 1990) is not able to boot => "missing operating sytem". If I select "Use a fix for older BIOS" the system just outputs "FreeDOS" without any progress.

I know there is the floppy only setup of FreeDOS but how can I use the content of the disk images if I cannot boot?

So how can I create a bootable FreeDOS system for an old 386SX laptop with Rufus or something else?

Comment: Have you looked up the resources provided at the [FreeDOS](https://www.freedos.org/) site(s)? Gone thru the [install-Howto](http://wiki.freedos.org/install/) and/or searched and/or asked at the [list](https://www.freedos.org/forums/) made especially for this? What were  the results?

Comment: 'CF disk' as in a CompactFlash card connected via an IDE adapter? Have you checked for [geometry problems](/q/22007/15334)?

Comment: If you put the CF card into the 386SX, boot from a floppy and install from a floppy, does it work? If you install on another machine, or on a card reader, you may not have the same geometry as what the 386SX natively uses with the card.

Comment: @Justme ok I see. Then I have to repair my Citizen U0DA-19A floppy drive (belt issue).

Comment: @leon22 Not necessarily. You can use e.g. DosBOX or other suitable VM/emulator to create/use/mount a disk image with any geometry you want, to match the geometry of your drive, then boot the VM from FreeDOS install floppy and install to the virtual HDD image. When you have the image, then clone it on the physical drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who are interested, there is another way to solve this problem:

use [86Box](https://86box.net/) (x86 Emulation), add a harddrive and set it to a maximum of 504MB (PreSet selection), insert the boot image of FreeDos and let the OS take care of partitioning and formatting,
install everything and use the created img file in Rufus to write it to the 4GB CF disk. After that I was able to boot on my 386 laptop. Yes ;-)

Comment: Ah ha! Your bios doesn't do CHS remapping; thus limit is 504MB. (Limit 16 heads, 63 sectors per track, 1024 cylinders.)

Answer (score 8):

Since you can't boot a FreeDOS install floppy on the target machine, you can make a disk image, and mount/use it with identical geometry in a virtual machine, and then install the OS in the virtual machine, by booting it from floppy and installing to the virtual HDD image. When done, clone the HDD image to the CF card.

The trick is, you still need to figure out what geometry your target computer wants to use on the CF card. Some CF card data sheets tell the geometry, but it usually is the simulated hardware CHS geometry such as 7750/16/63 for a 4GB card, which may or may not be translated by the BIOS with some algorithm to logical CHS geometry such as 968/128/63.

But the 386SX is likely so old that it can't do geometry translation, so most compatible CF cards would be max 500MB. It may detect or use larger cards incorrectly, or just hang when presented with a larger card. At least it did not hang, but be sure the CF card size and geometry is detected and set correctly.

Comment: To check this hypothesis, use boot sector (back up MBR on CF card, and write this to it; then restore later) will tell you the geometry. Yes it's base 10. Base64 image: McCJ//z6jtC8AHv7jtiOwInHzRNyMojI
JD+0AOgyAL6DfOhHAIjQtABA6CQAvnp8
6DkAicjQwNDAJMCG4OgRAL6OfOgmAOsG
vpt86B4A9Ov9UVK5CgC+/3vGBAAx0vfx
gMIwTogUCcB18lpZuwcArLQOzRCsCMB1
98MgaGVhZHMNCgAgc2VjdG9ycw0KACBj
eWxpbmRlcnMNCgBFcnJvciENCgA= Source: https://github.com/joshudson/dossuperfloppy/blob/master/hdgeometry.asm

Comment: @Joshua I don't think calling INT 13H with AH=0 returns the geometry, or does it? At least AH=8 would.

Comment: @Justme I referenced your comment in a bug report to that repo, along with another bug: https://github.com/joshudson/dossuperfloppy/issues/2

Comment: @Justme: Yeah that's a bug. My system appears to return something approximating the disk geometry for the last disk on the system. Guess which disk I tested with. Updated base64 image: cCJ//z6jtC8AHv7jtiOwInHtAjNE3IziMgkP7QA6DMAvoZ86EgAiPC0AEDoJQC+
fXzoOgCJyCTA0MDQwIbgQOgRAL6RfOgmAOsGvp586B4A9Ov9UVK5CgC+/3vGBAAx
0vfxgMIwTogUCcB18lpZuwcArLQOzRCsCMB198MgaGVhZHMNCgAgc2VjdG9ycw0K
ACBjeWxpbmRlcnMNCgBFcnJvciENCgA=

Comment: @Joshua I did not try that but I played with getting the geometry yesterday so it should work. A related side note that the 0xAA55 signature is missing at offset 0x1FE so many BIOSes would not run that if they check for the signature.

Comment: @Justme: No AA55 isn't missing; it's supposed to overwrite the bootloader leaving the partition table in place.

Comment: @Joshua OK, but which tool should be used to install that? It needs to read the original boot sector, apply your program over the code area, and write whole sector back.

Comment: @Justme: `cat hdgeometry.bin > /dev/sdc` or something like that.